# Schema error with SalesForce wsdl

Tags: wsdl, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I have been working with an Apex class in SalesForce that has been working perfectly in terms of updating, generating the new WSDL and updating the reference in Visual Studio. Yesterday I added a new method and now I get an invalid schema error in VS when trying to update the reference. I tested the validaty of the WSDL here [www.wsdl-analyzer.com](http://www.wsdl-analyzer.com) and sure enough it gave me the error:

***The reference ns1:ID in the XML Schema references a type or element that is not defined. Please make sure that your Schema documents are correct.***

Looking at the xml file I can see that even in visual studio it doesnt like this particular line or several of the others as well:

```
<xsd:element name="CreatedById" minOccurs="0" type="ns1:ID" nillable="true"/>
```

The first few lines of the xml file look like (I've replaced parts with xxxx for privacy but they refer to the SF instance):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/xxxx" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/xxxx" xmlns:AvailabilityExtended="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/AvailabilityExtended" xmlns:BookingWrapper="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/BookingWrapper">
 <types>
  <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/AvailabilityExtended">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You generated wsdl with your custom class?

Comment: Yes, I click the Generate WSDL button on the APEX class in SalesForce and am trying to reference that in Visual Studio either by local file or the SF URL directly

Comment: The default way to generate a wsdl is to go to Setup -> API -> Generate Enterprise WSDL.
What do you mean by "APEX class"?

Comment: You also generate them individually, Develop -> Apex Classes -> Click WSDL on the relevant custom class.